# direction routing

Tags: latitude-longitude

Is there any link like this "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino"...where instead of address i can pass latitude longitude values of the places

Answer (score 1):

http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?geocode=&q=51+N+5+E

for 51 N and 5 E